# Alert user before navigating to external site URL ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, url, navigation, external

Working on an ASP.NET application that has primarily a few master pages which controls rest of the pages and user controls in the application. We have a request from a client that would like to warn the user if they try to navigate to any other external site. So for example, if our application was www.abc.com and if they were in abc.com/user,  abc.com/payment, etc and they were to type www.yahoo.com and try to navigate away, we need the ability to alert the user that they are navigating away from the application to some other site. We are looking for a way to either to accomplish this via Javascript(if possible) or any other alternate .NET way. Worst case scenario we can even consider a 3rd party tool (not preferred though).

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle javascript **window** object events. Google DOM events.

Answer (score 0):

I have done similar but works in IE. Although the solution is not a proven but worked for me. The solution is simply JS function on window.onbeforeunload event. Basically we need to consider two things here:

1. if user clicks outside of our website area meaning back/forward buttons or closing browser etc - the window.event.clientY will be negative.
2. if our website is showing some popup windows, need to ignore them because it's part of our website.

{

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) 
 {

  var currUrl = document.URL;
  e = e || window.event;
  var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;

 if (y < 0) 
 { 
   //call session end logic here
   //check URL in case you have popup windows in your website
   if (currUrl.indexOf('<popuppagename.aspx') >= 0 || ...)
     return;
   else
    //user is navigating away so show alert
  }
 }
```